# Spring Boot on Websphere application server 9

Tags: spring-boot, websphere

Working on sample spring boot application using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.5 with security. Main spring boot application class extends SpringBootServletInitializer. War file generated and works fine in tomcat. I deployed same war file on websphere application server and the application starts but it looks like spring boot is not getting initialized. I don't see any error in log. Is thre anything should be done for the application to initialize in websphere?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by updating web.xml from

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
   <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

to latest format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsc" 
 id="webApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).